# python regex fetching column details from ddl

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
USE test_db2
CREATE  TABLE test_table2
(
    Subscn_Purch_Id                 BIGINT COMMENT 'from deserializer',
    Price_Amt                       DECIMAL(38,18),           
    Purch_Line_Item_Id              BIGINT,  
    Subscn_Purch_Status_Id          BIGINT COMMENT 'from defdf',
    Offer_Coupon_Id                 BIGINT,    -- INTRO OFFER
    Offer_Period_Hrs                BIGINT,
    discount_offer_id               STRING     -- DISCOUNT
)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
testcol bigint
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'eeee' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'rrrr' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'tttt';
```

from the above DDL I need to get the column level details.
ie,
column name,
data type,
data length (if any present)
data precision (if any present)
column comment (if any present)

I don't need the comment details like '-- INTRO OFFER' and '-- DISCOUNT' in the above sample.

I have tried using the regex

```
\s*(\w+)\s*(\w+)(?:\s*\,\s*)?(?:\((\d+)(?:,\s?(\d+))?\))?(?:\s*\,\s*)?(?:(?=(?:.*COMMENT\s*)\'(.*)\'(?:\,|\))))
```

this regex is fetching the details that have 'COMEMNT' word In it but not the others.on adding '?' at the end of this regex ,its fetching the details which I son't need.

how to achieve this.

attaching the regex101 link :

https://regex101.com/r/QfOCfj/3

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is usually not a good idea to try to parse these strings with regular expressions. That being said, you could try to use the newer `regex` module which supports `\G`:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\()
\s*
(?P<column_name>\w+)\s+
(?P<column_type>\w+)
(?:
    \(
    (?P<column_size>[^()]+)
    \)
)?
[, ]+
.*
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jcCBch/1/) and mind the modifiers.

---

Alternatively - if installing another module is not an option - use two expressions:

1. Fetch every block of `(` and `)` first recursively
2. Analyze that block with the above expression minus the first line

Answer (score 0):

The regex by @Jan might get you what you want, but there is potentially a much cleaner way to go about this.  You may try just querying the information schema tables directly in DB2.

```
SELECT
    COLNO,
    SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME,
    DATA_TYPE, 
    COALESCE(PRECISION, LENGTH) AS length,
    SMALLINT(SCALE) AS scale,
    STORAGE
FROM QSYS2/SYSCOLUMNS
WHERE
    SYSTEM_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db' AND
    SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME   = 'test_table2';
```